# Fragment slide up animation doesn't show fragment underneath

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-animation

When opening a fragment I need to add an animation to slide it up from the bottom and then when that fragment closes it needs to slide back down off the screen.

I have the following code in the fragment that slides up, which is almost working:

```
public override Animator OnCreateAnimator (FragmentTransit transit, bool enter, int nextAnim) {
        var display = this.Activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
        var size = new Point ();
        display.GetSize (size);
        var displayHeight = size.Y;

        var animator = enter ? 
            ObjectAnimator.OfFloat (this, "translationY", displayHeight, 0) : 
            ObjectAnimator.OfFloat (this, "translationY", 0, displayHeight);
        animator.SetDuration (300);
        return animator;
    }
```

There is one issue around the slide up animation... It immediately shows the fragment's white background and action bar (it doesn't animate), the content below the action bar does slide up. This means that you lose the effect of showing the previous fragment underneath the new fragment as it slides up, as you just see the white background behind the content sliding up.

Sliding back down works correctly, the fragment over top slides back down and you can see the fragment beneath it as it slides down.

Here is the code that opens the new fragment, in case it's relevant:

```
var transaction = activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
transaction.Replace (navigationContext.ContainerResourceId, fragment, fragment.Name);
transaction.AddToBackStack (fragment.Name);
transaction.Commit ();
```

Any ideas as to how I can make the slide up animation work correctly, showing the fragment underneath as it slides up?

Comment: chang replace to add transaction.add(navigationContext.ContainerResourceId, fragment, fragment.Name);

Comment: Boom shackalacka!! That did it... Can you repost that as answer, and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using replace meaning remove previous `fragment`.Try to use add:

```
var transaction = activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
transaction.add(navigationContext.ContainerResourceId, fragment, fragment.Name);
transaction.AddToBackStack (fragment.Name);
transaction.Commit ();
```

Answer (score 0):

One good way to accomplish this is to set your animators in xml and set the transition animation during the transaction.

```
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(
                R.animator.slide_in_from_right,
                R.animator.slide_out_left,
                R.animator.slide_in_from_left,
                R.animator.slide_out_right);
```

Example animator code:

```
<objectAnimator
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:propertyName="translationX"
android:duration="400"
android:valueFrom="1.0"
android:valueTo="0.0"
android:valueType="floatType"/>
```